# How to disappear Bootstrap popover using AngulatJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am using bootstrap popover by this fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/ivankovachev/U4GLT/

It's working when I click the text the popover is coming. in second click it's disappearing(toggling). it's fine.

Now, my requirement including toggling  when I click any other place in page then popup should disappear.

I am trying. Please help me to do that.

```
customDirectives = angular.module('customDirectives', []);
customDirectives.directive('customPopover', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<span>{{label}}</span>',
        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
            scope.label = attrs.popoverLabel;
            $(el).popover({
                trigger: 'click',
                html: true,
                content: attrs.popoverHtml,
                placement: attrs.popoverPlacement
            });
        }
    };
});

angular.module('CustomComponents', ['customDirectives']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use event.stopPropagation function

here is working plunker:
http://jsfiddle.net/U4GLT/2681/

```
customDirectives = angular.module('customDirectives', []);
customDirectives.directive('customPopover', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<span>{{label}}</span>',
        link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
            scope.label = attrs.popoverLabel;
            $(el).bind('click', function(event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                $(el).popover({
                    trigger: 'click',
                    html: true,
                    content: attrs.popoverHtml,
                    placement: attrs.popoverPlacement
                });
            });
            $(window).bind('click', function(event) {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    $(el).popover('hide');
                });
            });

        }
    };
});

angular.module('CustomComponents', ['customDirectives']);
```

Comment: ya, it's working, but is there any other way without using $(window)

Comment: You can use http://www.markschabacker.com/blog/2014/12/26/angular-any-other-click/ this aproach if you want